# Why is Random Forest classifier slower when n_jobs increases?

Tags: python, random-forest, scikit-learn, model-evaluation

So I am using an example random forest classifier found on a blog :

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import timeit

iris = load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)
df['is_train'] = np.random.uniform(0, 1, len(df)) <= .75
df['species'] = pd.Categorical.from_codes(iris.target, iris.target_names)  
train, test = df[df['is_train']==True], df[df['is_train']==False]
features = df.columns[:4]

def test_func():
    clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=-1)
    y, _ = pd.factorize(train['species'])
    clf.fit(train[features], y)
    return clf
```

Now, I am trying to run the code faster, but somehow increasing the number of jobs slows the calculation instead.

For example :

```
timeit.timeit(test_func,number=100)
```

If n_jobs = 1 : returns 1.1 second

If n_jobs = -1, or any value >=2 : returns 13 seconds !

The code is running on windows 10 64 bits on Intel i7 4770K processor or Ryzen r7 1700 with the same problem.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which processor is giving you a better performance in scikit-learn? 4770K or the r7 1700?

Comment: Depends on the jobs. On simple monothread, the i7 is faster. However, when multithreading is possible then the ryzen is much faster (more than twice on some examples)

Comment: Thanks mate! Internet is full of gaming benchmarks which I don't want :P. Planning to buy a r5 1600X.

Answer (score 3):

OK, so the answer is pretty obvious. Everything is working fine.
The problem is that the calculation runs too fast (less than 1e-3 second).
Launching a multithreaded calculation has some cost that slows the code.

I have done the same calculation but with a much larger data file and now, using n_jobs > 1 allows for faster computation.